# Grails - Multiple Tables in Single Domain Class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have two tables with a common primary key. Now i want to get data from that both tables and show in single view using that primary key.

How i can get both table data in single domain class? How can i specify mapping?

For Example

Table-A and Table-B both are in single schema ABC

```
class X {
   int id
   String name

   static mapping = {
      table name: "Table-A", schema: "ABC"
      columns {
         name column:'name'
      }
   }
}
```

now i want to get address from table-B so that my view looks like below

```
ID  NAME  ADDRESS
2   HSJHD  23 X-Street Washington USA
```

How to get two table data in single domain class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a foreign key relation, you would simply use belongsTo in each object (provided a one-to-one relationship). 
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html

Otherwise you could create a database view on your database, then create a domain object to match that view.  Creating a domain based on a database view is identical to creating a domain based on a table.

Comment: I have tried BelongsTO but it doesn't work. Since i have legacy database and no permission to change the database, How can i do it? What is Join Table in grails? Can you please put solution on above code?

Comment: I have no idea what problems you are getting, so I have no idea how I could post a solution more than suggesting methods of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Few options

1. Just use hql to query and join on the primary key
2. Create a view from the two tables, and map new table to that view
3. Use belongs to and when u access one object then access the other

Comment: put code example for belongsTO. I cant figure out . There is no blog post over this. Its is really hard since getting error

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use constraints: http://www.grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Constraints/Usage.html

and http://www.grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html#constraints

Comment: I dont see two tables mapping in single domain class. Do you understand my question? Give example for above code.